# Why storing a literal value which is whole number in nature in a Float datatype in java without 'f' at the end don't give an error?

Tags: java, types, floating-point, double, literals

```
float firstFloatValue = 5;

float secondFloatValue = 2.5;
```

Why is that the first variable without an **f** at the end doesn't give an error while the second variable does?
I know that if we don't put an **f** at the end of the literal, it is assumed as a double. But why there is not an error while initializing the first variable by 5 without an **f** at the end. 
Please help me, I am very new to Java.

Error message:

```
Main.java:12: error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to float
        float secondFloatValue = 2.5;
```

Comment: Because of type casting firstFloatValue example int is type casted to float. But in second double cant be type casted to float.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of type casting firstFloatValue example int is type casted to float ( small memory data types into higher memory data types ) default behaviour. 
But in second double cant be type casted to float

Answer (score 1):

You didn't include the error message (ALWAYS include the error message on StackOverflow).

Without the type suffix `f` (as in `2.5f`) the literal `2.5` is interpreted as a `double`, which does not fit in a `float` variable.

Comment: “Fitting” is not the issue. The `int` type also does not “fit” in the `float` type; both `int` and `double` values may need to be rounded when converted to `float`. Java or this implementation seems to have made an inconsistent decision here. One either ought to warn about converting source types that can represent values that are not representable in the destination type (even if in range) or, if compile-time values are involved, warn if the actual source value is not representable in the destination type. Warning for one source type but not the other is inconsistent.

Comment: @EricPostpischil It might indeed have been better to limit widening primitive conversions to true subsets, such as float to double or int to double, but that is not how it is defined in the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2).